# JavaScript importing and scanning text file

Tags: javascript

I am trying to convert a Java program I wrote into JavaScript.

One of the functionalities of the program include importing a text file that has about a thousand words, separated with line breaks between every word.

In Java, importing this text file and putting it in an array variable was easy, since I could use Scanner.nextLine() and for loops. But I have no idea how I am supposed to do this in JavaScript.

Is there an object analogous to Java's scanner in JavaScript? How can I achieve this task?

Comment: If you're doing this with Node, you need to use the [File System](http://nodejs.org/api/fs.html) module. Otherwise you'll have to explain more about your project, because the simple answer to your question is "no".  JavaScript has no native library support for file access.

Comment: @Pointy - Well, there's [local files support](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/file/dndfiles/) (if supported by the browser)?

Comment: @JaredFarrish yes but that's not *native* support - it's part of the browser context, just like the Node file system stuff is part of the Node environment. By "native" I mean stuff like Date, RegExp, etc.

Answer (score 0):

You can split a string into an array (of strings) easily:

```
var words; // array of words
var text;  // the input text string containing all the words

words = text.split("\n");
```

If you need help on *how to you obtain the text from a file* (or a http server) I'll edit my answer as you'll provide mode information in your question.

Comment: I need info about how to obtain the text from a file. What more info do you need?

Comment: 1) where is the file. 2) where does your code run (is it inside a browser or is it a script run with Node, for example)

Comment: the files will be in a folder accessible to the script. I am using Intel XDK, and I am fairly sure the code will run in a browser.

Answer (score -1):

Using jQuery :

```
$('#somediv').load('some.txt', function(__textdata){
});
```

Comment: I don't think that's what the OP is asking for here.